# Suggestions for Math Equation OCR tool with API

Tags: latex, image-processing

I am looking forward to converting equation images to tex/mathml. All the equations are computer printed. So, not so worried about the clarity. We have around 100K images and hence looking for some solution with API access or an on-premise/offline option.

Our problem is to display all the equations online and also process them for comparison and similarity. If we can get the images converted to Tex/Mathml, the problem becomes a bit simplified.

Comment: This is not a research question in mathematics. Anyway, the solution to your problem is https://mathpix.com/.

Comment: I think so as well. I could only find mathpix.com as a solution. It is a bit expensive for bulk images but still gets the job done well. It was surprising to see there is only 1 such solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have had quite good results in math OCR with [InftyReader](http://www.inftyproject.org/en/software.html#InftyReader). Some post-processing of the LaTeX output is needed, but the bulk of the work is done automatically.

Here is an example of a [scanned page](http://www.inftyproject.org/demo/sample1.tif) and InftyReader [output.](http://www.inftyproject.org/demo/sample1_result.pdf)

This is proprietary software, but you can use it offline.

Comment: Checking it out. If it is an on-prim offline solution, it might also work. Thank you.
The only other solution that I could find with API support is [mathpic.com](https://mathpic.com)